# Why not generalize the concept of prime numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

A prime number is a natural number N > 1, that is divisible only by 1 and N (N/1).
The number 1 is given special treatment in this definition, and this can be generalized by extending the set of the specially treated numbers, for example to also include number 2, lets call these secondary numbers:

A secondary number is a natural number N > 2, that is divisible only by 1, N/1, 2, N/2.

This gives us a completely new set of 'prime numbers' that have many qualities of prime number set,
theres infinitely many of them and it seems the fundamental theorem of arithmetics is also true for this set.

Would this set be somehow less special than that of prime numbers?
Did anyone already do this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  So a secondary number is twice a prime?

Comment: Hi, not at all, for example 8 is a secondary number, while 4 is not a prime.

Comment: If I do not miss something, $8$ is the only example not being twice a prime.

Comment: If I understand well, in addition to $8$, these are simply numbers of the form $2p$, where $p$ is prime.

Comment: Is $4$ a secondary number?

Comment: it cannot be simply 2p as many of them are odd numbers, maybe it could result in set of primes + 2p + 8 though

Comment: yes 4 is a secondary number, it cannot be divided by nothing else than itself and its half

Comment: As for generalizations of primes... you might be interested also in [Semiprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime), those numbers who are the product of exactly two primes.  The set of numbers you describe (*apart from 8*) are a subset of this.

Comment: I think that 8 appears is the only interesting fact of this definition. Can we generalize it, i.e. if I allow 1,2,3,N/3,N/2 and N, which other strange numbers pop up corresponding to 8?

Comment: Another generalization would be the numbers with exactly $3$ divisors , exactly $4$ divisors and so on. Or "almost primes" (semiprimes having no divisor upto $N^{1/3}$)

Comment: @Peter, see my answer

Comment: As I read the comments, both $4$ and $8$ are secondary numbers, so the fundamental theorem of arithmetic fails for this set of numbers, as $16=2\cdot 8=4\cdot 4$ has two distinct factorizations into secondaries.

Comment: @KeithBackman:  a secondary number is $>2$ per OP

Comment: @J. W. Tanner My bad. How about $64=8\cdot 8=4\cdot 4\cdot 4$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one natural generalization along these lines:

> A natural number $n$ is $k$-*prime* when it has exactly $k+1$ positive divisors.

Then $1$-prime is the same as ordinary prime. And $0$-prime is the unit $1$. Also, a $2$-prime is the square of a prime but a $3$-prime is the cube of a prime or the product of two primes.

The problem with this generalization is that $k$-primes do not occur naturally in number theory and so are not very useful.

Comment: Wouldnt that mean that 9 is a 2-prime, as 9 has 3 divisors (1, 3, 9) ?

Comment: @Salamander86, yes, $n$ is a $2$-prime iff $n$ is the square of a prime